# How to restore a quote in Magento when returning to the Onepage checkout?

Tags: magento, enterprise, checkout, quote

I am using Magento Enterprise, with a Datacash 3D Secure payment module.

In the event of an error during the payment process I want the user returned to the onepage checkout with their basket intact. Currently when the user returns to the checkout the basket is empty so they are then forwarded to the "checkout/cart" because they have no items.

I thought it might be a problem with my code so I have the initial payment action redirecting straight away with an error back to the onepage checkout.

```
 public function redirectAction() {
  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError("There was a problem with the payment gateway. Please try again");
  $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
  return $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/', array('_secure'=>true));
}
```

However on returning to the checkout page the basket is empty. Adding in the following log into the indexAction of the onepage checkout I get "Quote ". Looking in the database the quote has had its active status set to 0.

```
 error_log("Quote ".Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId());
```

I have not came across this problem with the standard Magento only with Enterprise. Has anyone come across this issue? Ideally I do not want customers having to add products to the basket again. Its like its conflicting with some sort of Magento Enterprise module.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you answered your own question. load the quote (if it's not available) and perform this:

```
$yourQuote()->setIsActive(true);
```

Comment: The trouble is that needs to be done on the onepagecheckout, however the error_log shows their is no quote against the session. I could always create a new session variable to store it and refer to it later on, but that seems a bit hacky. Ideally I need to stop the thing that is clearing it in the first place.

Comment: I found that in Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage always sets the quote to be inactive, as soon as it starts creating an order. Your right just by loading my quote at the start of my controller at setting it to active keeps the basket in tacked when the user returns to the checkout. Also if the user hits back during the 3DSecure process.

Comment: Couldn't you just override the default checkout action and at the head of it do this logic followed by parent::checkout(); or whatever the method is called?